# custom package import issue -- attribute error

Tags: python

I have a custom package and the below file structure...when I do `import pkg_name` it imports it but `pkg_name.add(1,3)` throws `attribute add not found` error

```
Dir/
   pkg_name/
       __init__.py
       test.py
```

init.py

```
from pkg_name.test import Test
```

test.py

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    def add(self,a,b):
        return a + b
```

How can I have it work with pkg_name.method? I'm using python 3

Comment: `add` is a function within an object, you need to initialize your object and then use that to call `add`

Comment: What do you want to happen when you call `pkg_name.add`?  It's defined as an instance method, so as written you need an instance of the class.

Comment: you can alternatively make it a `staticmethod` you don't need to keep track of state here whatsoever so there's no point for your class to pass `self` to `add`

Answer (score 1):

"add" is an instance method, you either need to create a "Test" object to invoke the method, or just redefine "add" as a function outside the "Test" class so you can access it with the "pkg_name.add" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__.py` file defines all the members of the package, i.e. every variable `x` defined will be accessible as `pkg_name.x`.  Currently the only member defined is `pkg_name.Test`, because the import statement assigns a reference to the class as a variable named `Test`.

You could access the `add` method as `pkg_name.Test.add`, but as written currently that requires an instance of the `Test` class because it's an instance method.  The shortest hack to make your example work would be to create an instance and immediately invoke its method without saving saving it, like so:

```
pkg_name.Test().add(1, 3)
```

But that's probably not what you want.  One way to make `add` a function of `pkg_name` would be to move it out of the `Test` class and import it, like so:

```
 # pkg_name/test.py

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

def add(a,b):
    return a + b
```

.

```
# pkg_name/__init__.py

from .test import Test, add
```

Then you could call it like `pkg_name.add(1, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script using the module should be something like:

```
from pkg_name.test import Test 

my_test = Test()
answer = my_test.add(1, 3)
```

If you just wanted to make a function `add()` available in your package, change the package itself:

```
def add(self,a,b):
    return a + b
```

(instead of the class definition.) You can then just use it like this:

```
from pkg_name.test import add

answer = add(1, 3)
```

Code in a module or package doesn't have to be wrapped in a class, but perhaps you were just trying your hand at writing classes.

Also, if you want something in a class, but it is completely independent from what is in an instance of the class, you should add it as a static method:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    @staticmethod
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b
```

Note how `Test.add()` doesn't reference `self` at all in your code, so it's better to leave it out and have the method of the class be 'static'. If you want to reference something in the class, but not in an instance, you could also turn it into a `classmethod`, read up on that elsewhere though, there's lots of examples of all three types of methods out there.